# How do I reference the dark theme icons in the windows phone 7 sdk?

Tags: windows-phone-7

the dark theme is located here

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.0\Icons\dark

How do I reference this file for example appbar.next.rest.png in the following

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar.prev.rest.png" Text="Previous"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar.next.rest.png" Text="Next"/>

....
```

Answer (score 3):

For application bar icons you don't need to switch the paths for different themes. The way application bar uses the image as a mask over the appropriate theme colour. This way you only need to provide the white and transparent image.

You can read more about this at [Creating Custom Application Bar Icon](http://www.kirupa.com/windowsphone/creating_custom_applicationbar_icon.htm)